# Windows 7: Creating shortcut / short command for commandline

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line-interface, shortcut

My Windows Command Line didnt recognize the command openssl. Therefore I downloaded it from here http://deanlee.cn/programming/openssl-for-windows.

But now, everytime I want to use this openssl tool, I have to write the following into my commandline: http://deanlee.cn/programming/openssl-for-windows

```
/Users/"myName"/Desktop/opensslforwindows/bin/openssl
```

For using this command I would just like to write

```
openssl
```

Shouldnt be too hard, but I dont have a lot command-line experience, and I couldnt find these information with google.

Comment: Why not install and use something like cygwin which has openssl built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click 'Computer', go to 'Properties', 'Advanced System Settings', 'Advanced' tab.  Click 'Environment Variables'.  Find 'PATH' in User Variables, and add ';/Users/"myName"/Desktop/opensslforwindows/bin/openssl' to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add /Users/"myName"/Desktop/opensslforwindows/bin/openssl
to your environment path.